# How to Left join with 2 subselects in Entity Framework Linq?

Tags: c#, sql

how to write this query in c# with Entity Framework?

```
Select Id, Name, DeliveryAdress, InvoiceAdress from Company 
left join (Select Address.CompanyId as CompanyId, Street + ' ' + ZipCode + '     ' + City as DeliveryAdress from Address 
join AddressType on AddressType.AddressTypeId = Address.AddressTypeId
where AddressType.Name = 'Delivery') sub1 on sub1.CompanyId = Company.Id
left join (Select Address.CompanyId as CompanyId, Street + ' ' + ZipCode + ' ' + City as InvoiceAdress from Address 
join AddressType on AddressType.AddressTypeId = Address.AddressTypeId
where AddressType.Name = 'Invoice') sub2 on sub2.CompanyId = Company.Id
```

In Fact I have 3 Tables: Company, Address and AdressType and in this query I have to select the ID and Name from the Company and 2 Adresses selected by typename...

Comment: Off-topic but I'd keep it as View in SQL server?

Comment: you may take the help of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Get List Of DeliveryAddresses by joining Address and AddressTypes

```
var deliveryaddresses=
from addr in db.Addresses join (addrtype in    
db.AddressTypes.Where(at=>at.Name=="Delivery")) on addr.AddressTypeId equals 
addrtype.AddressTypeId select new {CompanyId=addr.CompanyId,
DeliveryAddress= addr.Street + " " + ZipCode + " " + City}
```

Next Get List Of Invoice Addresses by joining Address and AddressTypes

```
var invoiceaddresses=
from addr in db.Addresses join (addrtype in    
db.AddressTypes.Where(at=>at.Name=="Invoice")) on addr.AddressTypeId equals 
addrtype.AddressTypeId select new {CompanyId=addr.CompanyId,
InvoiceAddress= addr.Street + " " + ZipCode + " " + City}
```

Then Perform Left Outer Join On DeliveryAddresses and invoiceAddresses

```
var deliveryandinvoiceaddresses=from da in deliveryaddresses join ia in    
invoiceaddresses on da.CompanyId equals ia.companyId into addrgroup from ag     
in addrgroup.DefaultIfEmpty() select new   
{CompanyId=da.CompanyId,DeliveryAddress=da.DeliveryAddress,InvoiceAddress= 
(ag==null?string.Empty:ag.InvoiceAddress)}
```

Finally Perform Left Outer Join on Company and the result of outer join of delivery and invoice addresses

```
var completelist=from c in db.companys join d in deliveryandinvoiceaddresses   
on c.Id equals d.CompanyId into compgroup from cg in 
companygroup.DefaultIfEmpty() select new {CompanyId=c.Id, 
Name=c.Name,DeliveryAddress=(cg==null?string.Empty:cg.DeliveryAddress), 
InvoiceAddress=(cg==null?string.Empty:cg.InvoiceAddress)}
```

Hope it solves the problem.